# simple 'printf' in bash gets screwed up output

Tags: bash, printf

I'm a newbie here. I've really tried to google it but failed.

I've got a simple script that reads from file line by line and then prints it. "b.txt" has the first line of "02083192846".

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf 'downloading %s .html\n' $line
done < "$1"
```

however, the output is screwed up:

```
User@User-pk ~/test
$ ./test.sh b.txt
 .htmlading 02083192846
```

Once this is fixed, my next question is how to use this line as part of the file name that some command will store into. i.e. the filename should be "02083192846.html". I've tried setting using it as ${line}.html but it doesn't work. For example `grep "foo" -f ${line}.html` doesn't work. But `curl http://foo -o $line.html` does work still!

Comment: File has Windows line-endings (`\r\n`, not just `\n`). Use `dos2unix` to it, or similar.

Comment: thanks for prompt help! Indeed, how silly it is. fixed with `cat b.txt | tr -d '\015' > a.txt` as was found on Stack as well!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf 'downloading %s .html\n' "${line//$'\r'/}"
    #                                      ________  
done < "$1"
    #                                          ^ 
    #                          remove \r with bash parameter expansion
```